# Using Applescript to find and delete "\n" in xml file

Tags: xml, sed, applescript

I have successfully accessed a db using Applescript, psql and write an xml file locally. This xml file however contains the line breakers "\n" all over and hence I have trouble to use the xml data as intended. A simple find/replace in TextEdit works - which I now would like to do in Applescript.
Typical xml data looks like this with all the "\n":

```
<row xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">\n  <reduction>95.79</reduction>\n  <name>360mm</name>\n  <name>ABC</name>\n  <description>test with eyemark</description>\n  <one_up_repeat>180</one_up_repeat>\n  <one_up_across>650</one_up_across>\n  <foil_width>650</foil_width>\n</row>\n\n
```

I have now tried this:

```
do shell script "/bin/cat /Users/alex/016136.xml | /usr/bin/sed 's/\\n/ /' > 016136.xml"
```

but get

```
sh: 016136.xml: Permission denied
```

Is there a better way than shell sed to find and delete all "\n" in the xml file? Thank you, Alex

Comment: I don't know about syntax for applescript, so not sure what the issue is... however, no need to use `cat`... `/usr/bin/sed 's/\\n/ /' /Users/alex/016136.xml` will do... and your title says delete, in which case it should be `'s/\\n//'`

Comment: and seems you are trying to write back changes to same file.. in which case you should use `-i` option (see https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/3640/in-place-editing/12529/portable-use#t=201705240653187241344)... if `016136.xml` and `/Users/alex/016136.xml` are meant to be same file, you'll get empty file

Comment: @Sundeep Thank you very much. I am now using this:
do shell script "/usr/bin/sed -i.original 's/\\n//g' /Users/alex/016136.xml"
However, the '\n' are not deleted and the file is unchanged without any error message. Any idea? Thanks, Alex

Comment: does the command work if you use it from terminal? if so, issue is likely due to something in applescript which I don't know about... also, did it create a backup file `016136.xml.original`?

Comment: @Sundeep, good question - yes, it works perfectly in Terminal. The backup file though is created as well when run in AppleScript. Hence the usr/bin/sed -i.original part works whereas the 's/\\n//g'  part got an issue. Alex

Answer (score 0):

Got it! This works:

```
set myFiles to (choose file with multiple selections allowed)
repeat with aFile in myFiles
    set myData to do shell script "cat " & quoted form of (aFile's POSIX path)
    set newData to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of myData & " | sed 's/\\n//g' > " & quoted form of (aFile's POSIX path)
end repeat
```